# Rarfile python module keeps throwing an error when trying to extract contents from a *.rar file

Tags: python

So im trying to simply extract the contents of a rar file into another location-

```
import rarfile

epath='C:\\Users\\sidharth.m\\Desktop\\Rar\\xyz.rar'

def unrar(file):
    rf = rarfile.RarFile(file)
    rf.extractall()

unrar(epath)
```

But im getting the following error -

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 2816, in
> >     custom_popen raise RarCannotExec("Unrar not installed?
> >     (rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL=%r)" % UNRAR_TOOL) rarfile.RarCannotExec: Unrar
> >     not installed? (rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL='unrar')

Ive already tried adding and installing the rarfile and unrar packages through anaconda prompt and cmd, ive also added their respective paths into the environmental path variables and if that wasnt enough i even imported them into the project folder.

Any idea why this problem could be happening?

Comment: the import youre using uses an underlying library directly from your OS. Waht OS are you using?

Comment: @Fire im using windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import rarfile

rarfile_full_path='PATHTOFILE\\xyz.rar'
path_to_extract='NEW_PATH_OF_YOUR_CHOICE'

def unrar(file,path):
    rf = rarfile.RarFile(file)
    rf.extractall(path)

unrar(rarfile_full_path,path_to_extract)
```

And you need to install **unrar** or **bsdtar** on your machine; just the **rarfile python package** *is not enough*

From the API Doc:

> Compressed files are extracted by executing external tool: either unrar from RARLAB or bsdtar from libarchive.

---

> Ive already tried adding and installing the rarfile and unrar packages
>   through anaconda prompt and cmd

Check if you can *unrar* from your *cmd* first, outside of *python*

Comment: When you say - "Check if you can unrar from your cmd first, outside of python" what do you mean? I have tried unrar in python cmd and it has thrown the same error, i have also tried unrar from cmd as it is and it said it is unrecognised.

Comment: the *rarfile* package use the *unrar* tool on your system; i.e.> It's not "autonomous"; if *unrar* doesn't work on your system, it'll never work on python. So, you need to do what it takes to get your *unrar* installation working properly on your Windows System, and then, try it on python. Open up a system console *cmd* (not python, don't open python) and try *unrar* command; if doesn't work properly, you need to fix that first, and only after that, try again inside python. If you have *unrar* installed on your system, probably you need to add *unrar* to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: I have already tried to add them to the PATH environment variable but i understand that the problem may lie in the method in which i may have installed 'unrar'.Will work on this further.
Thanks for the help :)